# comparing a string to any permutations of @" "

Tags: objective-c

I want to compare a string a1 and get answer as YES if a1 contains any permutation of @" ". How can I do that? I have tried the following but it does not work.

> NSString *a1;
>
> BOOL isequals=([a1 compare:@"      " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,2)]==NSOrederedSame);

Comment: What do you mean by "any permutation of @" ""? How can there be a permutation of a single space?

Comment: @rdelmar it means the string can contain any number of spaces, it was obtained as a substring from a string derived from a txt file, hence why the multiple spaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSString *a1;
NSRange range = [a1 rangeOfString:@" "];
if (range.location == NSNotFound)
{
   //not equal
}
```

Edit: Use this one will more fit your requirement

```
BOOL isEqueal  = (range.location != NSNotFound);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Don't check the length. Check to see if the range location is NSNotFound.

Comment: BTW - I didn't down vote but your updated answer appears backwards. Using `==` means the `if` statement will be true if no space character is found. It should be `BOOL isequals = range.location != NSNotFound;`.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *string;
if ([string rangeOfString:@" "].location == NSNotFound) {
   //Do your stuff
} else {
   //Do your stuff
}
```

The key is noticing that `rangeOfString:` returns an `NSRange` struct, and [the documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_) that it returns the struct `{NSNotFound, 0}`

---

And if you're on iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite, you can now do:

```
NSString *string;
if ([string containsString:@" "]) {
   //Do your stuff
} else {
   //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This could never work. How can the first two characters of `a1` compare equal to a single space? And why do a case insensitive compare against a space character? Besides all of that, based on the OP's comment, the goal is to see if `a1` contains a space.